# Laravel 5.8 - Creating a maintenance order and attaching to a car by foreign key working, but not displaying on web page

Tags: php, sql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I hope I can ask this question correctly. I have a form to create a car and then another form to create a maintenance order that you can select a car by it's ID to create some maintenance for whichever car was picked. And it works fine in my database I get back the exact car_id selected and they look connected. However, in my browser it is saying that my cars have no relation, and I believe it has something to do with how I create the child in the controller? Am I overwriting the car_id with the request possibly? Here is some code for context.

BLADE for Create:

```
@section('content')
    <div class="card-body border rounded">
        <form action="{{ route('maintenance.store') }}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            @csrf
            <div class="form-group">    
                <div class="col-sm-8">
                    <label class="col-sm-4 col-form-label" id="useCar">Use Selected Car</label>
                    <select class="form-control" id="selectCar" name="car_selected" required focus>
                        <option value="" disabled selected>Please select car</option>        
                        @foreach($cars as $car)
                            <option value="{{$car->id}}">{{ $car->make }}</option>
                        @endforeach
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
            <fieldset class="form-group">
                <div class="row">
                    <legend class="col-form-label col-sm-2 pt-0">Maintenance Work: </legend>
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <div class="form-check">
                            <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="oil_changes" id="gridChecks1">
                            <label class="form-check-label" for="gridChecks1">Oil Changes</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-check">
                            <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="tire_rotations" id="gridChecks2">
                            <label class="form-check-label" for="gridChecks2">Tire Rotations</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-check">
                            <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="tune_ups" id="gridChecks3">
                            <label class="form-check-label" for="gridChecks3">Tune-ups</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-check">
                            <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="repairs" id="gridChecks4">
                            <label class="form-check-label" for="gridChecks4">Repairs</label>  
                            </div>
                        </div>
                </div>
            </fieldset>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="maintenanceNotes">Maintenance Notes</label>
                <textarea class="form-control" name="notes" id="maintenanceNotes" rows="3"></textarea>
            </div>
            <br>
            <button class="btn btn-success">Maintenance Request</button>
        </form>
    </div>
@endsection
```

BLADE for Index:

```
@section('content')
    <div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
            <thead>
                <tr class="text-center">
                    <th scope="col">Make</th>
                    <th scope="col">Model</th>
                    <th scope="col">Year</th>
                    <th scope="col">Colour</th>
                    <th scope="col"></th>
                    <th scope="col">Maintenance on Car</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @foreach ($cars as $car)
                    <tr class="text-center">
                        <th scope="row">{{ $car->make }}</td>
                        <td>{{ $car->model }}</td>
                        <td>{{ $car->year }}</td>
                        <td>{{ $car->colour }}</td>
                        <td class="align-center">
                            <a class="btn btn-warning btn-md m-auto" href="{{ route('car.edit', $car) }}">Edit Car</a>
                            @if($car->maintenances)
                                @foreach ($car->maintenances as $maintenance)
                                    <a class="btn btn-warning btn-md m-auto" href="{{ route('maintenance.edit', $maintenance) }}">Edit Maintenance</a>
                                @endforeach
                            @endif
                            <a class="btn btn-danger btn-md m-auto" href="{{ route('car.destroy', $car)}}" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete {{$car->make}}?');">Delete</a>
                        </td>
                        @if($car->maintenances)
                            @foreach ($car->maintenances as $maintenance)
                                <td><a class="btn btn-info btn-sm" href="/maintenance/{{ $maintenance->id }}">See Maintenances done</a></td>
                            @endforeach
                        @endif
                    </tr>
                @endforeach
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    <a class="btn btn-success btn-sm float-left ml-2" href="{{ route('car.create') }}">Add Car</a>
    <a class="btn btn-success btn-sm float-right ml-2" href="{{ route('maintenance.create') }}">Create Maintenance Order</a>
    <a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm float-right" href="{{ route('export') }}">Export Car Maintenance Data</a>
@endsection
```

ROUTES:

```
Route::get('maintenance/create', 'MaintenanceController@create')->name('maintenance.create');
Route::post('maintenance/store', 'MaintenanceController@store')->name('maintenance.store');
```

CONTROLLER:

```
public function store()
    {
        $car_id = request('car_selected');
        $oil = strtoupper(request('oil_changes', 'off')) == 'ON';
        $tire = strtoupper(request('tire_rotations', 'off')) == 'ON';
        $tune = strtoupper(request('tune_ups', 'off')) == 'ON';
        $repair = strtoupper(request('repairs', 'off')) == 'ON';
        $note = request('notes');

        Maintenance::create([
            'car_id' => $car_id,
            'oil_changes' => $oil,
            'tire_rotations' => $tire,
            'tune_ups' => $tune,
            'repairs' => $repair,
            'notes' => $note
        ]);

        return redirect()->route('car.index');
    }
```

MODELS Car:

```
class Car extends Model
{
    protected $guarded = ['id'];

    protected $fillable = [
        'make', 'model', 'year', 'colour'
    ];

    public function maintenances()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Maintenance::class, 'id');
    }

}
```

MODELS Maintenance:

```
class Maintenance extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'car_id', 'oil_changes', 'tire_rotations', 'tune_ups', 'repairs', 'price', 'notes'
    ];
    
    protected $casts = [
        'date_completed' => 'date:hh:mm'
    ];

    public function car()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Car::class);
    }
}
```

Comment: If the DB looks fine then it is probably just an error on the displaying. Can you show the view where you display the connection? As well as the Models?

Comment: Aless55 - I added the view and the two models, hope that helps!

Comment: What I see is that you don't need the if around the loops. If no maintenances are present the loop won't execute. Another thing is that the foreign_key defined in your maintenances() methid is most likely not id. I guess it will be car_id? If your foreign keys match the laravel best practices you can remove this entirely.

Comment: @Aless55 Thank you so much! It was the maintenances() method that was causing the issue, I removed the 'id' and that worked perfectly.
`code return $this->hasMany(Maintenance::class);` 
Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

For anyone that may have this issue in the future, it was my Car model causing the issue. To fix it I just removed the 'id' from the method. So now the maintenances method looks like this:

```
public function maintenances()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Maintenance::class);
    }
```